# Simplifying jQuery/Javascript code

Tags: javascript, jquery, algorithm, simplify

I've been trying to simplify my code using an '$(input[data-code]").each' function in order to simplify a code. The code is just handling when a user clicks on an anchor link, it animates it down to that spot, it looks like:

```
$('a.welcome').click(function(){
    $('html, body').animate({scrollTop:0}, 2000, function() {
        parallaxScroll(); 
    });
    return false;
});

$('a.step1').click(function(){
    $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: $('#step1').offset().top - 70}, 2000, function() {
        parallaxScroll(); 
    });
    return false;
});

$('a.step2').click(function(){
    $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: $('#step2').offset().top - 70}, 2000, function() {
        parallaxScroll(); 
    });
    return false;
});

$('a.step3').click(function(){
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $('#step3').offset().top - 70
    }, 2000, function() {
        parallaxScroll(); 
    });
    return false;
});
```

And what i've come up with so far to simplify it looks like this:

```
$("input[data-code]").each(function() {
    $(this).click(function(){
        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: $($(this).data("code")).offset().top - 70
        }, 2000, function() {
            parallaxScroll(); 
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

But it doesn't seem to be working :(

My theory is that the `$(this).click(function(){` isn't actually properly calling the elements in the style `$(a.welcome).click(function(){`

The actual HTML for the links looks like so:

```
<nav id="primary">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <h1>Welcome</h1>
            <a class="welcome" href="#welcome" data-code="0">View</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <h1>Step 1: Setup</h1>
            <a class="step1" href="#step1" data-code="#step1">Step 1</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <h1>Step 2: Data Management</h1>
            <a class="step2" href="#step2" data-code="#step2">Step 2</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <h1>Step 3: Configure Cameras</h1>
            <a class="step3" href="#step3" data-code="#step3">View</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: You don't need the `each()`; `click()` already adds a handler to every element.

Comment: I may be missing something, but why is your selector on element input when you are using anchor elements?

Comment: One thing to reduce apparent complexity would be to replace all `function(){parallaxScroll();}` just with `parallaxScroll`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd do it like this, I think.
You want to target anchor tags.

```
$("a[data-code]").click(function(){
    var val = $(this).data("code") ? $($(this).data("code")).offset().top - 70 : 0;
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: val
    }, 2000, function() {
        parallaxScroll(); 
    });
return false;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use this in on click function

```
$('#primary a').on('click', function () {
    var offSet = $($(this).data('code')).offset().top - 70;
    if ($(this).is('.welcome')) {
        offSet = 0;
    }
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: offSet
    }, 2000,

    function () {
        parallaxScroll();
    });
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

a simple

```
$('#scroll a').click(function(){
    $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: $(this).offset().top - 70}, 2000, 
    function() {
        parallaxScroll(); 
    });
    return false;
});
```

and adding `id = "scroll"` to the `ul`

```
<nav id="primary">
        <ul id = "scroll">
            <li>
                <h1>Welcome</h1>
                <a class="welcome" href="#welcome" data-code="0">View</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <h1>Step 1: Setup</h1>
                <a class="step1" href="#step1" data-code="#step1">Step 1</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <h1>Step 2: Data Management</h1>
                <a class="step2" href="#step2" data-code="#step2">Step 2</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <h1>Step 3: Configure Cameras</h1>
                <a class="step3" href="#step3" data-code="#step3">View</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
</nav>
```

would work.

Answer (score 0):

Your jQuery code is targeting HTML input tags instead of anchor tags.

Change:

```
$("input[data-code]").each(function() {
```

to:

```
$("a[data-code]").each(function() {
```